# Discord.js how to add role to a specific user ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot for my friends and I only so I hardcoded our discord ID's. Now I'm trying to make the bot assign us roles using our IDs.

Here's what I have so far and it's giving me an error.

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
    const guild = bot.guilds.get("OUR SERVER ID");
    let mcRole = guild.roles.find(x => x.name === "Minecraft Players");
    let johnMember = guild.members.get("id", "JOHN'S ID")
    johnMember.addRole(mcRole);
})
```

Error says:

```
johnMember.addRole(mcRole);
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined
```

Comment: It looks like the error is from a different line, could you post the code it's referencing?

Comment: Try `guild.members.get("id", some_id).addRole(mcRole)` instead, you're trying to assign a role to a list of members, not a specific member.

Comment: @Tobsta sorry I corrected the error. I tried that line but now it says 
`guild.member.get is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I do `bot.on('message', message` Because `ready` Not Working. I hope it works

```js
bot.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
    let johnMember = message.guild.members.get('user ID');
    let mcRole = message.guild.roles.find('name', "Minecraft Players");
    if(!mcRole) return;
    if(!johnMember) return;
    if(johnMember.roles.has(mcRole.id)) return;
    johnMember.addRole(mcRole.id);
});
```

You need to send any message to run this command.